# Web application aspx css printing issue

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm using a JavaScript function call a pop-up window to print out my label, and the function include the CSS link. The problem is it seems that the CSS doesn't affect the printing page when I preview it, I have no idea which portion when wrong. Anyone can please give me advice?

JavaScript code:

```js
function ConfirmButton() {
    if (true) {
        var prtContent = document.getElementById("<%=printing.ClientID %>");
        var WinPrint1 = window.open('', '', 'scrollbars=yes,letf=0,top=0,width=400,height=430');
        WinPrint1.document.writeln('<body><link href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css"rel="stylesheet" /><link href="Printing.css"rel="stylesheet" media ="print"/>');
        WinPrint1.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
        WinPrint1.document.writeln('</body></HTML>');
        WinPrint1.document.title = "Test Printing";
        WinPrint1.document.close();
        WinPrint1.focus();
        WinPrint1.print();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

CSS page name "Printing.css":

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: `<link href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css"rel="stylesheet" /><link href="Printing.css"rel="stylesheet" media ="print"/>` should be inside `head` and not `body`

Comment: @ingalion It's still going to work if its inside the body.  That's more a recommendation these days than a strict guideline.  You're technically right, but modern browsers don't really care where it shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background colors aren't rendered when printing ... and that's a good thing.  A printed page has its own medium with its own background colors, unlike a screen which is much more dynamic and multi-variate.  Being able to paint the canvas on a screen makes much more sense than on a page.

If, for some reason, you really wanted to print a section in red, you could wrap the entirety of your content in a container, and do some CSS wizardry like so:

```
<section class="page-container">
  <div>All my content...</div>
  <div>All my content...</div>
  <div>All my content...</div>
</section>
```

```
.page-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
}
.page-container:after {
  content: url(data:image/png;base64,...LONG BASE64 STRING...==);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-container > div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

## [Here's a fiddle illustrating the general concept, try printing it.](http://jsfiddle.net/xbrzjxm0/)